# Connect to a SFTP-server using FileZilla

Tags: 14.04, sftp, filezilla

I have an issue when I'm trying to connect to a SFTP-server using FileZilla. I'm sure that the server is up and running, but I just get:

```
Error: Server unexpectedly closed network connection 
Error: Could not connect to server
```

[image]

I'm trying to connect to a server by using `sftp://WhateverLinkToServer.com` and the port is `22015`, tried to open the port in the firewall with no luck. I'm positive that the username and password is correct.

Is there any method to debug this, a log-file or something to show if I'm missing anything, or do you have any other suggestions of how to solve my problem?

**Update:**
I was able to connect via the terminal directly to the SFTP-server. Any suggestion on what the problem is with my FileZilla? Is there something wrong with my key fingerprint?

Cheers,
Magnus

Comment: Just wondering.. you have installed openssh server and allowed logins ? (sudo apt-get install openssh-server)

Comment: Yes, openssh server is already installed.

Comment: just check your port is opened for outer world. https://pentest-tools.com/discovery-probing/tcp-port-scanner-online-nmap if it is not showing, it should be a firewall or portforwarding issue if it is behind  a nat gateway...

Comment: I doubt it because the person next to me (a mac user and on the same network) was able to connect with no problem, but I'll give it a try on another network where I know the port should not be a problem

Comment: I think there is a real issue here, something which occurs with (certain versions of) Filezilla and particular server config or software versions, i.e. it's not a problem with firewalls, port forwarding etc.. I can consistently reproduce it With Debian8+mysecureshell and Filezilla 3.7.3-1ubuntu1 (the version in the 14.04 repositories).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing... The whole time I was using an older version of FileZilla (3.7.3) installed via apt-get and could not get this one to work. After downloading the newest version (3.10.3) it worked like a charm. Thanks for your help tho!

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me too. But I only had this problem with a Debian 8 server, the old Filezilla 3.7.3-1ubuntu1 version worked fine with e.g. Debian 7 (and serverside mysecureshell in both cases).

Answer (score 0):

I think this maybe a problem with your forwarding. Please check if your Network and Firewall has this Port open and forwarded. If you like to share a screenshot it would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Well I'm on a school network and can't check if the port forward-settings on the router, but the person next to me (a mac-user) was able to connect to the same server using FileZilla. Here is a screenshot of FileZilla: [Screenshot](http://i61.tinypic.com/2unxabt.jpg)

Comment: Best thing is to contact sftp server administrator.. Otherwise it would be a wastage of time.. Who knows what type of rules applied server level and what is the network infracture etc..

Comment: Alright, thanks for your answer tho, I'll contact him asap.

Comment: I so your last edit now.. can you telnet 22015 ? tellnet whateverLinkToServer.com 22015

Comment: @Aravinda Yes, telnet works.

Comment: May be something to do with active / passive ftp in filezilla settings.. not sure though.. https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration#Passive_mode_2

Answer (score 0):

Server added your IP address to deny list due to repetitive connection failed attempts. Provide your  IP address to SFTP server administrator and inform him to remove your IP address entry from "/etc/hosts.deny" file.

Comment: I'll try to come in touch with him.